# Prob with moving sprite in SFML looks laggy (because of sf::Clock)

Tags: time, sfml

I'm trying out SFML and am creating the classic game Snake.

I've successfully made the snake move a certain amount of pixels after a certain amount of time. The problem is that it takes different time for the gameloop to execute. So when I write out the differtime for every move it looks like this:

- Time: 0.273553
- Time: 0.259873
- Time: 0.260135
- Time: 0.396735
- Time: 0.258397
- Time: 0.262811
- Time: 0.259681
- Time: 0.257136
- Time: 0.266248
- Time: 0.412772
- Time: 0.260008

The bumps with 0.39 and 0.41 are not good. They make the snake sometimes move slower and does not look good at all.

The time should always be 0.25 so that the snake will run smoothly on the screen.
Here is my code that is implemented in the gameloop (snake.getSpeed() function returns 4):

```
    if(_clock.GetElapsedTime() > (1 / snake.getSpeed())){
        std::cout << "Time: " << _clock.GetElapsedTime() << std::endl;
        snake.changeDir(keyDown);       //Change direction
        snake.move();           //Move the snake
        _clock.Reset();
    }
```

Is the processor just to slow or do anyone have another idea on how to make the code better?

EDIT: IGNORE THE ABOVE. The real time bumper seems to be as the GetEvent functions. Don't know why but it takes all from 0 to 0.2 seconds to execute. Here is my test code:

```
    //This is just i bit of code, therefore there's no ending brackets ;)
    _clock.Reset();
    while(_mainWindow.GetEvent(currentEvent)) {
        std::cout << _clock.GetElapsedTime() << std::endl;    //cout the elapsed time for GetEvent
```

(The _mainWindow is a sf::RenderWindow)
Don't know if this can be fixed but I'm leaving question unanswered and if anyone got an idea then that's great. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds to me like you are looking to move the sprite at a constant velocity. There is a relevant conversation here: http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=6284.0 The short version is that you should calculate the snake's position using the velocity you desire times the amount of time elapsed since the last update.

Comment: I've read about this, but I don't think this is what I need. Instead I move the snake every 2 seconds. I will look at your post when I have time though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I advise you to use SFML 2, because SFML 1.6 hasn't been maintained for over 2.5 years, has quite a few known and ugly bugs and lacks many nice features from SFML 2.

Next it's mostly better to not trying to force a certain framerate, since there are factors one can't really do something about it (OS interrupts, lots of events when moving the mouse, etc.), but rather make the movement depend on the frame-rate.
The simplest way would be to use the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method):

```
pos.x = pos.x*velocity.x*dt
```

Where `pos` is a vector of the position of an object, `velocity` is a vector for the two-dimensional velocity and `dt` is the delta time, i.e. the time between two frames.
Unfortunately the simple Euler method isn't very precise and maybe the [Verlet integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration) could give a smoother movement.

But that's again not all, because even though the movement is now more tightly bound to the frame-rate, spikes will still occur and lead to unwanted effects. Thus it's better to fix your time steps, so the rendering with it's FPS (frames per second) count is independent from the physics calculation. There are again many approaches to this and one article that I've found useful is [that one](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/).